# How to increase a CSS value by the value of a JS variable?

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, position

I have several fixed position divs with the same class at varying distances from the left edge of the window, and I'd like to increase/decrease that distance by an equal amount on each div when a certain action happens (in this case, the window being resized). I've tried positioning them with CSS and percentages rather than pixels, but it doesn't quite do the job.

Is there a way to store the position of each of those divs in an array and then add/subtract a given amount of pixels?

Here's what I've tried so far - I'm still getting my head around JS so this could be really bad for all I know, but here goes:

```
roomObjects = $('.object-pos');

var objectCount = 0;

for ( var objectCount = 0; objectCount < 10; objectCount++;) {
          roomObjects = rooomObjects[objectCount];
          console.log(roomObjects.css("background-position").split(" "));
        }
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing why percentages wouldn't work? Usually that's what I would recommend if you're wanting the page to scale correctly on window resizes.

Comment: Sure - I have the divs set against a background image that is set to `background-size:cover` and `background-position: center top` unless the window is smaller than size of that background image, in which case my js disables the background-size style. I need the divs to stay lined up with the background image where I've positioned them so that if the window is smaller than the bg image, the divs move with it.

Comment: you could add another "content" div with width and height set to the window size and then have the divs in question reside within that. That way, the containing div is always the size of the whole page, and then the background sizing doesn't really matter. Your divs will scale with the containing one. (i hope i'm understanding the issue right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mind sharing why percentages wouldn't work? Usually that's what I would recommend if you're wanting the page to scale correctly on window resizes. I guess if you really wanted to you could do something like:

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
    $('#whateverdiv').style.whateverproperty = $('#whateverdiv').style.whateverproperty.toString() + (newPosition - oldPosition);
    oldPosition = newPosition;
}
```

this is obviously not the complete code, but you should be able to fill in the blanks. You'll have to set the oldPosition variable on page load with the original position so that the function works the first time.

edit: you'll also have to strip off the units from the x.style.property string, so that you'll be able to add the value to it

Comment: Thanks for the help - I know my question is kind of vague, it's because I'm not exactly sure how to articulate what it is I'm after in this case, but this has helped :)

Answer (score 0):

A problem you might well be facing is that when retrieving the current left or top properties, they are returned as a string, with `px` of `%` on the end. Try running a `parseInt()` on the returned values to get a number, then you might well be able to add to the values. Just be sure, when reassigning, that you concatenate "px" or "%" on the end as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bit of jQuery :

```
var el = $("#id");
var top = el.css("top");
el.css("top", top * 1.2); // increase top by 20%
```

saves mucking around in the DOM

This might be useful if you want to position things relatively: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Position